# In an Access 2007 form with detail view, how do I set the the up/down arrow keys to move focus between records rather than controls..?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

In Microsoft Access 2007, in a table/query in **datasheet view**, the UP/DOWN arrow keys act as one might expect: they they move the focus up/down by one record, to the same control as in the previous record. It's similar to moving around cells in Excel, and makes it easy to quickly move around a datasheet to adjust values.

However...on a **form with a detail pane**, the left/right arrow keys act instead like TAB and SHIFT+TAB. They move the focus back & forth through the controls in the defined Tab Order, rather than back & forth through the detail records.

I cannot find anything in the Access Options, help file, or Google to explain how this might be changed.

Without changing the Tab Index or Tab Stop properties of the controls, how do I make the arrow keys move focus back & forth through the detail records on a form, rather than back & forth through the controls in tab order..???

Comment: Use Datasheet View. Then the Up/Down arrows will move between records and Left/Right move between columns. Unless maybe code in Key (Up/Down/Press) event can control the arrow key behavior. Never tried, no desire to.

Comment: Unfortunately, using the form in datasheet view is not viable, as there are MS Forms controls in the detail section which would become hidden. Remapping the arrow keys is an interesting suggestion; I'll experiment with it.